# Problems with R Request price feed through Bloomberg API

Tags: r, feed, bloomberg

Following the steps as outlined below:

install Java APIv3 from the Bloomberg terminal (by typing WAPI into the command bar). Once installed connect it to R using :install.packages("Rbbg", repos = "http://r.findata.org") and conn <- blpConnect(log.level = "finest"). Finally, to extract share price information you use bdp(conn,securities,function)

I get an error when trying to connect that gives me the following message:

Error in .jnew("org/findata/blpwrapper/Connection", java.log.level) : 
  org.findata.blpwrapper.WrapperException: Session not started because: CONNECTION_FAILURE

Any advice how to resolve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: is bbcomm.exe started (you can check in the list of windows processes)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try migrating to Rblpapi. This is more modern equivalent and can be found on CRAN (install.packages("Rblpapi")) or github (https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi).